# <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, >

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

why RDLC Report didn't create.

Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Comment: How did you create the RDLC file?  How are you executing the Report?  RDLC is html with a SQL Sever Query.  The RDLC file is loaded manually into the SQL Server Reports.  The error indicates the RDLC file is failing probably due to the html having errors.